# AWS ELB Route 53 to my bluehost domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

Currently I'm trying to put SSL on my EC2 Instance using `Load balancer` & `Route 53` for my `BlueHost` Domain

As of now I have working Load balancer

https://adthrone-loadbalancer-1188159040.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

and also I did some `Route53` like this

[image]

Is there something I need to reconfigure on my `BlueHost` account just to map my `adthrone.com` domain to my `ELB`?

**UPDATE**

Is this the name server that I need to add on my bluehost?

AWS UI

[image]

BlueHost UI

[image]

After placing the name servers and saves.

[image]

Comment: What is BlueHost?

Comment: Currently using bluehost as my domain name provider that I want to map to my load balancer

Comment: I see. Answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the list of nameservers ("NS records") at BlueHost to the 4 NS listed in Route53. Copy and paste one by one to BlueHost custom nameservers for your domain. Here are the instructions: https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/transfer_client_start

After that is completed wait some time for the old records to expire (it can take up to 1 day!)

Then the internet will know that the nameservers for adthrone.com are on AWS and your web url will start working.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hello MLu I updated my post please check if that is the record that needed to be added on my BlueHost Name Servers

Comment: @RaeIan Use the 4 nameservers from the right hand column: `ns-123.awsdns-987.org`, etc. All 4 of them. No need to redact it in the screenshot, nameservers are public information.

Comment: Mybad it so confusing for me. I already added the name servers located on the right hand and place it on my bluehost is that the final step? to map my domain on my ELB?

Comment: @RaeIan You did it right - I can already see the website on my phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5T9d.png It will take some time to propagate and expire the old nameservers, esp on your laptop as it probably has the old BlueHost nameservers cached. Give it a day or so, it should expire by then. Try from your phone or from some other laptop that didn't try to access it before in the meantime. Well done :)

Comment: Thankyou for assistance. Will get back here for the updates if the propagation ends. :)

Comment: Adter changing name servers on blue hosts based on the given name servers from AWS. adthrone.com is not working anymore but www.adthrone.com is working fine heres the link https://serverfault.com/questions/1015835/load-balancer-route-53-dns-address-could-not-be-found-aws-bluehost