# Load Balancer & Route 53 : DNS address could not be found | AWS & BlueHost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-route53

Hello I just wanna ask

Currently I have created a `load balancer` and `route 53`

In my route 53 I have these records

[image]

Now I have these name servers registered on my `BlueHost` (Mydomain provider)

[image]

Yesterday I just changed the name servers on bluehost based on the requirement of AWS after creating a record set (route53)

Now I can search this http://www.adthrone.com/

but not this

http://adthrone.com

Where this should working after changing the name server it just suddenly happened.

**UPDATE**

I created another `record set`

[image]

does this mean, `adthrone.com` should be working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have an **A record** for **adthrone.com**. Create the same **A ALIAS** like you did for *www.adthrone.com* and it should work.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hello MLu i updated my post.

Comment: @RaeIan yep that’s the one. Again it may take some time to propagate as everything with DNS. It’s not Amazon’s fault, nature of DNS.

Comment: Does the propagation time for what I did for www.adthrone.com is different to the propagation time of adthrone.com?

Comment: BIG THANKS !! @MLu https is now working I need now to fix my mixed content

Comment: @RaeIan Each record in DNS has its own TTL (time to live) and the caching countdown starts when a client first tries to access the name. Then there are ISP caches, your home router cache, etc. The bottom line is that different clients may see the old or new records for a period of time until *their* cache expire and they re-request it fresh from Amazon.